# Automatic pillars by host name

Tags: saltstack

I have problem where managing multiple domains in one `top.sls` file is getting difficult. How could I write `top.sls` so that it only takes those pillars that match my minion name/hostname.

For example:

- There is `deplo1.domain1.app` minion
- It loads `domain1_app` from `pillar/domain1_app/init.sls`

Current `pillar/top.sls`

```
base:
    '*':
        - global
    'system.*':
        - system
    'deploy*.*':
        - deploy

    '*.domain1.app':
        - domain1_app
    deploy0.domain1.app:
        - domain1_app.deploy0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.reddit.com/r/saltstack/comments/5b4l9v/storing_pillars_specific_to_a_host/ by user "dekonnection":

Put something like this in your pillar's `top.sls`:

```
base:
  '*':
  [...stuff that can be shared for multiple hosts defined here...]
  '{{ grains.host }}':
    - ignore_missing: True
    - hosts.{{ grains.host }}
```

Now you can write a specific `<pillar root>/hosts/<hostname>.sls` file for host-specific settings for each host that needs them, and if a host does not need anything specific to it, `ignore_missing: True` allows you to omit the file.

You can do the same using any other grains if necessary.